# Copying initial Global offset table

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, elf, glibc

I am trying to develop a function that would basically reset the Global Offset table at any moment during execution. The first step is to find the way to the entries which I successfully reached by getting the address of `DT_JMPREL` then add the base address. then loop through the number of entries that has `_JMPSLOT_` type.

I tested out the code and compared its function addresses with gdb output and it works fine. Now comes the question, which part in the `glibc/elf/` files should I check to go through a list of all the shared libraries but the GOT entries still points back to the PLT instructions (before lazy binding/same way as it is in elf)? I think `dl-load.c` might be the one but I am not quite sure where exactly should I do so

Answer (score 0):

Initial relocation happens in `elf/dl-reloc.c`, around here:

```
#include "dynamic-link.h"

    ELF_DYNAMIC_RELOCATE (l, lazy, consider_profiling, skip_ifunc);
```

This is a place where glibc still uses nested functions, and the whole thing is a bit … awkward. This code is also used for self-relocation of `ld.so`, so it cannot use function calls and global data access on some targets.